# Crash CarPlay demo on simulator

Tags: ios, swift, ios-simulator, carplay

Getting below crash when run Apple official CarPlay Demo on simulator but working fine in other system.

```
CarPlayTutorial[18440:282424] *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception  
'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: 'Unsupported object <CPTabBarTemplate: 
0x600000621170> <identifier: B5E32A00-9E81-4211-893F-4CC5FE7F2812, userInfo: (null), 
tabTitle: (null), tabImage: (null), showsTabBadge: 0> passed to 
setRootTemplate:animated:completion:. Allowed classes: (null)'
```

Comment: Did you at CarPlay in entitlement ❓

Comment: yes added @[PtitXav](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13944750/ptit-xav) , <key>com.apple.developer.carplay-audio</key><true/>

Comment: Resolved issue, Disable Open using Rosetta from get info of Xcode

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Got solution on M1 chip system disable Open using Rosetta.

Right click on the Xcode from application folder and select Get Info -> Disable Open using Rosetta option.

Comment: you can accept your own answer